# Flask + SQLAlchemy: Load database with records by running python script

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to load my database **ONCE** with SQLALchemy in a flask app. I thought i could add the records to the database by running a script from the terminal command, but it seems that i'm having difficulties executing the python script?

- Does initializing the app by running `export FLASK_APP=app/__init__.py` then `flask run` even loads the database?
- Does starting up the local server each time re

**folder structure:**

```
  app
    api
      __init__.py
      log.py
    tasks
      __init__.py
      test.py
    __init__.py
    models.py
    utils.py
```

**app/api/log.py**

```
from app import app
from app.models import Race, db
from app.utils  import * 

def historical_records():
    df_races, df_circuits, constructors, df_drivers, df_results = extract_to_df_race('results', seasons, races_round)
    # Check if row exists in table
    exists = db.session.query(db.exists().scalar())
    if exists is None:
        df_races, df_circuits, constructors, df_drivers, df_results = extract_to_df_race('results', seasons, races_round)
        save_races_to_db(df_races, db)
    else:
        print("The database already contains data of 2016 to current race")

def save_races_to_db(df_races, db):
    for idx,row in df_races.iterrows():
        r = Race()
        r.url = df_races.loc[idx,"url"]
        r.season = df_races.loc[idx,"season"]
        r.raceName = df_races.loc[idx,"raceName"]
        db.session.add(r)
        try:
            db.session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            db.session.rollback()
            print(str(e))


historical_records()
```

I activated the virtual environment, then executed `python app/api/log.py` but encountered this error:

```
  File "app/api/log.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
ImportError: No module named app
```

Does initializing the app by running `export FLASK_APP=app/__init__.py` then `flask run` even loads the database?

Comment: Your app is not a python file, how could you import it. You may try sth like `from ... import models` and remove that `from app import app`.

Comment: What's in your `__init__.py` file?

Comment: `db.session.query(db.exists().scalar())` either fails with an error or checks if `NULL` exists (not in a position to test exactly which of the two) and is not a useful check to make. It’s just an empty `EXISTS` statement.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that you are using a module inside a package as a script; at that point the top-level module import path is set to the `app/api/` directory. At the very least you’d run it as `python -m app.api.log` to keep the right context.

However, you should instead make your script a [Flask command](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/cli/#custom-commands), because that gives you an *an active application context*.

Make your `historical_records()` function the command:

```
import click

from app import app
from app.models import Race, db
from app.utils  import * 

@app.cli.command()
def historical_records():
    # your function
```

Remove the `historical_records()` call from the end of the module.

You can then run the command with

```
FLASK_APP=app flask historical_records
```

(You don’t need to add `/__init__.py` to `FLASK_APP`)

We can’t tell you if `flask run` will load the database because we can’t see either `__init__.py` or `db.py`, nor do I know if you ran the `create_all()` function.